# Change fragment TextView value from CustomView

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 2 fragments: GameFragment and PostGameFragment
In GameFragment i have a CustomView with a score of the player.

When the player loses i created a `onLoseListener` that tells the GameFragment to change to the PostGameFragment and i want to update a TextView there with the value of the score that is inside the CustomView.

How do i do this? 
I tried `textView.text = valueToUpdate` inside the CustomView but it gives me error: textView must not be null

Here is my PostGameFragment onCreateView method.
In this xml Fragment is the TextView i want to update.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post_game, container, false)
    view.postGameLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_postgame)

    view.button.setOnClickListener { view ->
        activity!!.supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_holder,GameFragment.newInstance() )
            .addToBackStack(GameFragment.toString())
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .commit()
    }

    // Return the fragment view/layout
    return view

}
```

And here is the method inside my CustomView, this method checks if the player loses if he doesnt then it adds +1 to the score.
I want to update the TextView with the score when the player loses.

```
fun checkLoser() {        
    if (ballInGame.posy >= height) {
        stopAnimation()
        onLoseListener.invoke()

    }else{
        score += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share a snippet of the code.

Comment: You can use interface to communicate between your Fragment and your Custom View and to update the text's value using it.

Comment: i updated the post with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your valueToUpdate not null and Binding your textview findViewById.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
textview.setText(valueToUpdate);
```